# What's this wireframe function color's code?

Tags: r, graphics, 3d, lattice

[image: example]

I tried to reproduce this color within wireframe function (lattice package in R). Anyone have an idea of its color code? It's only the question of presentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) (or MS Paint, or most any other drawing tool) to zoom in and use the colour picker tool to give you the color code for any selected pixel:

[image]